# Continuous Drawing does not happen UITouch`s touchMoved

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch

I am using UIKit to draw image pattern, when i draw line very fast its not recieved call Contineously in UITouch`s delegate.

Here is the code i am using

```
var tempImageView : UIImageView!
var patternImage = UIImage(named: "xxx.png")!

var brushWidth : CGFloat = 50.0
var opacity : CGFloat = 1.0
var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
```

UITouches`s delegates

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}
```

to draw pattern from image

```
func drawLine(fromPoint:CGPoint, toPoint:CGPoint) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    tempImageView.image?.draw(in: self.bounds)

    context?.draw(patternImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: fromPoint.x , y: fromPoint.y, width:brushWidth , height:brushWidth))
    tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    tempImageView.alpha = opacity
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Anyone can help me to fix this issue.
if difference between the two continuous touch is greater then brushWidth, space is there in drawing.

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

---

Comment: set `tempImageView's` alpha to 1.

Comment: its already there @vaibhav var opacity : CGFloat = 1.0

Comment: Maybe it's because of calling core context too many times. Try to profile with Time Profiler.

Comment: @Lumialxk, i have cheked, its because of the difference between last point & current become more when u draw line fastly, that is delegates behavior

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect? Check the drawing frame of your image being `CGRect(x: fromPoint.x , y: fromPoint.y, width:brushWidth , height:brushWidth)`. Your `drawLine` is not even using `toPoint` parameter.

It is also missing rotation and all.. You could perhaps improve your result by applying some matrix but from what it seems you are trying to achieve you are better off finding a better tool. Maybe you could iterate though something like:

```
var point = fromPoint
let direction = CGPointNormalize(CGPointMinus(toPoint-fromPoint))
while CGPointDot(CGPointMinus(point-fromPoint), direction)*CGPointDot(CGPointMinus(point-toPoint), direction) <= 0.0 {
    drawLineSegment(at: point) // This is the same method you already have without that other unused parameter
    point = CGPointPlus(point, direction)
}
```

Supposably this code should draw an image at start point then move by 1 "pixel" toward the end point and draw it again and repeat this until it reaches its destination. The methods should easily be written and understood for `CGPoint` operations. As for the logic:

It finds the direction toward the `toPoint` from `fromPoint` and goes toward it. The logic in the while condition is that as long as projections of the points from one and to the other border have opposite directions the point is still between the two border points and image needs to be drawn. I have not tested it though.

Comment: Yes you are right but i wanted to know the behavior of UITouch delegates, on what basis delegates get called

Comment: @iOS_Developer this seems completely different then the question. But the best way to IMAGINE how this system works is that your OS will try grab touch locations at certain frequency and store them in some stack. Your application may then at demand request those events, parse them and process them in events. What that means is you may not assume touch event frequency from the OS and you may not even assume the speed/delay at which you will receive events (if main thread is blocked you will have a lag). But currently it seems the frequency is relatively constant resulting in gaps in your case.